# Using mod_rewrite, how do I remove the path from an url when a user requests it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically what I'm trying to do is change what the url displays in the browser address bar. So if a user types **example.com/lang/en** I want the address bar to just display **example.com** removing the **/lang/en** part from what is displayed.

I've tried a few rewriteRules but it didn't work. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can not save `variable` by `mod_rewrite`

if you change `example.com/lang/en` to `example.com` you can not access to `lang/en` any more and changing language

the best way to do this is using `$_SESSION` and `header("location..")`

an example for `example.com/?lang=en`

```
session_start()

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
   $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
   header("location: example.com");
   exit;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
   $_SESSION['lang'] = "en" //default language
```

Comment: Hmmm ok. Fair point. Then I'll use mod_rewrite to remove the query from displaying then?

Comment: you can't use mod_rewrite after running a page, you should use header("location..") to change your location

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I miss-understood your request. Please try this.

```
<?php
  $uri = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  if ($lang_key = array_search('lang',$uri)) {
    $lang = $uri[$lang_key+1];
    unset($uri[$lang_key],$uri[$lang_key+1]);
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    header('location: http://example.com/'.implode('/',$uri));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the browser when an explicit request is made for `/lang/en`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /en/lang
RewriteRule ^en/lang/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

To internally rewrite the `/` requests back into `/land/en`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en/lang%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/lang/$1 [L]
```